# How to use FindSimilar function of Azure FaceAPI

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I read things in detail. And write another code now. Everything is fine except one error. I have put config.py and util.py in similar folder and set my 'key' and 'url' in config.py. I don't understand why this error is coming then?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a_similar1.py", line 40, in 
    find_similars(face_id, face_list_id, max_candidates_return, mode)
  File "a_similar1.py", line 37, in find_similars
    return util.request('POST', url, json=jsonb) 
  File "/home/afshan/Microsoft_Azure/phase_1/Cognitive-Face-Python/cognitive_face/util.py", line 106, in request
    error_msg.get('message'))
util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:
    status_code: 404
    code: ResourceNotFound
    message: The requested resource was not found.

The lines of util.py are :

```
# Setup the headers with default Content-Type and Subscription Key.
    headers = headers or {}
    if 'Content-Type' not in headers:
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    #headers['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = Key.get()
    headers['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = 'd7c5495c64a44bc692761cd7c45ad56e'

    response = requests.request(
        method,
        url,
        params=params,
        data=data,
        json=json,
        headers=headers)
```

code is:

```
import util
import uuid
import unittest

import cognitive_face as CF

face_id = None
face_list_id = None
max_candidates_return = None
mode = None

CF.Key.set('d7c5495c64a44bc692761cd7c45ad56e')
CF.BaseUrl.set('https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/')

def find_similars(face_id, face_list_id, max_candidates_return, mode):

    #face_id='5a27b8c3-f340-4559-baa3-a8dc770c5078', 
    face_id='bd930ddb-7f1d-4693-875d-3126a678dd68',
    face_list_id='ef799940-1305-11e9-bec1-080027226cb7', 
    max_candidates_return=100,
    mode='matchPerson'

    url = 'https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/'
    jsonb = {
    'faceId': face_id,
    'faceListId': face_list_id,
    'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': max_candidates_return,
    'mode': mode,
    }

    return util.request('POST', url, json=jsonb) 


find_similars(face_id, face_list_id, max_candidates_return, mode)
```

Comment: "I have write this code but its not working properly": what kind of error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the following as a payload:

```
payload = {'faceId': '5a27b8c3-f340-4559-baa3-a8dc770c5078', 'faceIds': 'ef799940-1305-11e9-bec1-080027226cb7', 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': 20, 'mode': "matchPerson"}
```

As the documentation states [here](https://southeastasia.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395237):

> faceIds (Array): An array of candidate faceIds. All of them are
>   created by Face - Detect and the faceIds will expire 24 hours after
>   the detection call. The number of faceIds is limited to 1000.
>   Parameter faceListId, largeFaceListId and faceIds should not be
>   provided at the same time

Here you are not passing an array in `faceIds`, it should be like the following:

```
payload = {'faceId': '5a27b8c3-f340-4559-baa3-a8dc770c5078', 'faceIds': ['ef799940-1305-11e9-bec1-080027226cb7'], 'maxNumOfCandidatesReturned': 20, 'mode': "matchPerson"}
```

---

### After edit of your question

You added the following error:

```
util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API: status_code: 404 code: ResourceNotFound message: The requested resource was not found.
```

The error you got is a 404, so the Url called is wrong. You should be calling `https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/findsimilars`, here you are only calling the root `https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0`. Fix the url

Comment: I've changed the code. Please see the code above and comment

Comment: I have tried both urls with and without findsimilars. None works

Comment: What is the error code that you have when you put the right url?

Comment: I think I got it: in your code your are setting the baseUrl, and then also adding this baseurl in the URL you are calling... replace "url = 'https://southeastasia.api.cognitive..." with only the complement to baseUrl, so it will be "url='findsimilars'"

Comment: For face.detection this code works perfectly. `import util import uuid import unittest import cognitive_face as CF CF.Key.set('d7c5495c64a44bc692761cd7c45ad56e') CF.BaseUrl.set('https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/') image = 'image.jpg' res = CF.face.detect(image) print(res) c = len(res) print('Total face detected:', c)` but for findsimilars same technique produces error **File "util.py", line 105, in request
    cls.person_persisted_face_id[name] = []
cognitive_face.util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:**

Comment: Here is the code for findsimilars : `import uuid
import unittest
import cognitive_face as CF
import util 

CF.Key.set('d7c5495c64a44bc692761cd7c45ad56e')
CF.BaseUrl.set('https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/')
print('1')

face_id = '5a27b8c3-f340-4559-baa3-a8dc770c5078'
face_list_id = 'ef799940-1305-11e9-bec1-080027226cb7'

res = CF.face.find_similars(face_id, face_list_id)
face_list_id=util.DataStore.face_list_id)
print(res)`

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more, it's impossible to follow your comments and question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186403/discussion-between-afshan-anwarali-and-nicolas-r).